# Swift ARKit's raycast is returning empty array

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, raycasting

I was trying to measure distance of some object from camera. It gave perfect result while using hittest. But, because hittest is now depricated, I was trying to replace hittest function. Following is my code. When I am printing query, it is giving something like this:
<ARRaycastQuery: 0x2822a2d80 origin=(-0.102434 -0.309679 -0.335700) direction=(-0.366751 -0.866715 0.338082) target=estimatedPlane>
which is not empty. But when I am printing result, it is returning an empty array.

```
var points: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 20, y: 184),
                             CGPoint(x: 442, y: 184),
                             CGPoint(x: 443, y: 184)]
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: true) { _ in
            measure()
        }
    }
    
    func measure() {
        if(buttonPressed){
            var i = 0
            for point in self.points{
                print(point)
                guard let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: point, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else { return } //.hitTest(point, types: .featurePoint)
                print(query)
                let results = sceneView.session.raycast(query)
                
                if results.isEmpty{
                    return
                }
                print(results[0])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?